# HTC Desire 816 CM12 Nightly SMS not working

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-desire

I just flashed and updated everything on my HTC Desire 816 and everything went just fine. But I followed [this](http://androidforums.com/threads/virgin-mobile-mod-universal-lte-virgin-mobile-apn-fix-wip-cm-aosp-4-4-x.840298/) APN fix and it doesn't seem to have worked as it should, and I haven't found anything on the thread.
It says I have LTE, it says my network is Virgin Mobile and that I'm in service on the Status page but I can't send any texts and when I scroll the status bar down it says "No Service".

I've never had to mess with APN settings before so I don't know what to do about any of this. The only thing I can do is connect to the internet without WiFi.

Sorry if this is a bit rambling. Like I said I've never had to mess with any APN settings before so I don't know what info is needed.

Also I can't actually find any "APN" settings, only VPN. Is this the same thing?

Another update: I get "No SIM card" when I unlock the screen. But that seems to be the only place

Comment: APN -> Access Point Names, while VPN -> Virtual Private Network, both are different and are used for different activities. As for where to find APN, try looking under "Settings -> More -> Mobile Networks -> Access Point Names" and tap Menu key or three vertical dots to add a new APN type.

Comment: "No SIM card" message is shown when the device doesn't have a SIM card inserted, or can't detect the SIM card because it's not inserted properly, or the baseband is unknown (may be the case here because it is not an unusual issue in case of flashing a ROM). Do confirm that your IMEI is also intact.

Comment: @Firelord I seem to randomly be in a bootloop. It's just stuck on the Cyanogenmod logo. 
I guess I'll reflash and see what happens